# KeyPairGenerator cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to create a little message system using RSA to encrypt the messages, but I'm stuck right in the beginning because for some reason, the code doesn't recognize KeyPairGenerator class.
My code so far, as following many examples on the Internet, is:

```
public class RSA {
    private KeyPairGenerator key_par_gen = null;
    private KeyPair kp = null;
    private PublicKey publicKey = null;
    private PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    private KeyFactory factory_rsa = null;
    private RSAPublicKeySpec pub = null;
    private RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = null;

    public RSA(){       
        setKey_par_gen(); 
        setKp(); //No error here
    }

    public void setKey_par_gen() {
        this.key_par_gen = new KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        //Error: Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
        //       KeyPairGenerator.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type  RSA.java    /RSA - Cloud/src    line 41 Java Problem

    }

    public void setKp() {
        this.kp = getKey_par_gen().genKeyPair();
    }
//....
}
```

I already updated to the latest java version, opened the KeyPairGenerator declaration and it's there, with the declared function and all.
Also can't be from the IDE, since I tried on Intellij, Eclipse and Netbeans.
Don't know what I'm missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: remove the `new` in front of `new KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");`. `KeyPairGenerator` is an abstract class with a static method `getInstance()`

Comment: Note that the Java compiler is looking for a nested class called `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance` with a constructor `getInstance(String)` in the code above. It will not find it (although it may find the method declaration) and likely shows a rather strange compiler error (in case anybody is wondering what the compiler error is all about).

Comment: I see a close vote for a "simple typographical error" but as this is a mistake that results in a complex error message and is very easy to make, I wouldn't mind **if it isn't closed**, even if it is a rather basic mistake to make. I find myself still typing `new` now and then when my mind tells my fingers to create an object instance while the objects *should* be created using the available factory methods. And I do think I'm relatively experienced with Java and crypto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instanciate a nested class `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance` which does not exist:

```
this.key_par_gen = new KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
// Error: KeyPairGenerator.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type
```

Instead, you need to call the static `getInstance()` method of `KeyPairGenerator` - simply remove the `new`:

```
this.key_par_gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
```